# What is the $2006^{\text{th}}$ term in the sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a sequence of integers, $t_1, t_2, \ldots; t_{n+3} = t_n+t_{n+1}-t_{n+2}$ for $n \geq 1$. If the first three terms, in order, are $1$, $3$, and $6$, what is the $2006^{\text{th}}$ term?

I thought this sequence would telescope and I would be able to find a closed-form expression for $t_n$ but that seems like it is not working. Also, there doesn't seem to be any pattern or period in the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but here's a simple solution:

Let's compute the first few terms:

$1, 3, 6, -2, 11, -7, 16, -12, 21, ...$

You notice an alternating positive-negative pattern, which might suggest to just look at every other term. Starting from the first term, you get:

$1, 6, 11, 16, 21, ...$

And starting from the second:

$3, -2, -7, -12, ...$

There's a pretty clear pattern here: Both are arithmetic sequences. So we get the formulas:

$$t_{2n + 1} = 1 + 5n, \qquad n \geq 0$$
$$t_{2n} = 8 - 5n, \qquad n \geq 1$$

Once you have this formula, it is very easy to prove by induction. Now, using the second formula:

$$t_{2006} = 8 - 5(1003) = -5007$$

Comment: I am  a little confused about how to prove it by induction. I assumed that $t_{2k} = 8-5k$ and then I got by the formula $t_{2(k+1)} = t_{2k-1}+t_{2k}+t_{2k+1}$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Alex Zorn you Ramanujan's Taxicab number of reputations right now.

Answer (score 1):

$t_{n+3}-t_{n+1} = -(t_{n+2}-t_n)=(-1)^n \cdot (t_{3}-t_1)=(-1)^n \cdot 5$

$\implies t_{n+3}=t_{n+1}+(-1)^n \cdot 5=t_{n-1}+((-1)^{n}+(-1)^{n-2}) \cdot 5= \cdots$

$\implies t_{2006}=t_{2004}+(-1)^{2003} \cdot 5=t_{2004}-5=\cdots =t_2-1002 \times 5=-5007$

Answer (score 1):

Another more abstract, (and easier to prove) way is using linear algebra. Given $\begin{pmatrix}t_{n+2}\\t_{n+1}\\t_n\end{pmatrix}$, we can use the recursive formula in your question to see 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t_{n+2}\\t_{n+1}\\t_n\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}t_{n+3}\\t_{n+2}\\t_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}$$

So you just have to compute 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^{2006}\begin{pmatrix}6\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

The rest can be done with a calculator. To do it by hand you'd want to Jordan decompose the matrix. It doesn't hurt that bad.